# How to control UI/Apps from shell?

Tags: ipad, ios, jailbreak, ssh

I have a jailbroken ipad (ios v. 7.1.1) and installed ssh, terminal and many admin tools. So far I am able to open/close an app from terminal and so much more... . Now I want to trigger UI events and control Apps(in effect touching a button, swiping, type a keyboard...) from terminal. Is there any (command line) tool that can help me accomplish that? I saw similar question [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/86702/controlling-ios-apps-via-command-line) but it is more than a year old (some tools might have emerged lately).

Comment: If your goal is just to control a Mac with an iPad (I din't know if it is or not), have you considered VPN, or are you looking strictly of a bash approach?

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX sorry if my question is not clear, but I wanted to control my ipad itself from shell (could be from local terminal or pc over ssh)

Comment: Ohh, i suggest you reword your question, it isnt very clear

Answer (score 1):

There's not really an easy method for this. There's no AppleScript implementation for interactions on iOS, unlike OS X, so if you really want this you're probably going to have to make it happen yourself with your own custom app.

Even with your own app, there's no easy way of doing interaction.

> On Cocoa Senior (also known as "the Mac") we have methods like the gargantuan:
>
> ```
> mouseEventWithType:location:modifierFlags:timestamp:
>   windowNumber:context:eventNumber:clickCount:pressure:
> ```
>
> to generate events.
>
> Cocoa Junior on the iPhone doesn't have any methods like this, so we must work out how to achieve it ourselves.

This is outside the scope of this site, but see the following site for more information:

- http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/synthesizing-touch-event-on-iphone.html

Answer (score -1):

I think what you are looking for is the ["Open"](http://moreinfo.thebigboss.org/moreinfo/depiction.php?file=openData) tweak for jailbroken devices. Apps can be launched like this:

`open com.identifier.here`
An example would be `open com.invoxia.triby` for an app that I use.

Thanks so much!

Comment: That works for opening apps, which the asker says they already can do. In this question, they are looking for a way to "trigger UI events and control apps," which cannot be accomplished with the `open` command.